# How do I handle an encoding error in Excel Power Query?

Tags: excel, postgresql, encoding, powerbi

I receive the following error when connecting to a Postgres database.

> DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [22P05] ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xc2 0x96 in encoding
> "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"; Error while executing the query
> Details:
> DataSourceKind=Odbc
> DataSourcePath=database=XXXXXXXX;dsn=PostgreSQL30;encoding='utf-8';port=XXXX;server=XXXXXXXXX
> OdbcErrors=Table

It only happens with this table, so the connection works in general. I would prefer to deal with this at the excel level and not make changes to the database. I tried including 'encoding='utf-8' in the connection string, but I see that the problem isn't that excel doesn't recognize the encoding scheme but that it doesn't have a process to handle 0xc2 0x96 in WIN1252.

Is there a way to change excel default encoding or a way to specify it in the connection string or query settings to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing the unicode Postgres driver and setting the dsn to it.

Comment: Windows strings are natively Unicode, since the first Windows NT version back in 1994. All Windows applications at this point (and for the last 20+ years) are Unicode.